# How to obtain peer's QSslCertificate after successful SSL handshake

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, https, qnetworkaccessmanager

When doing a HTTPS request using Qt, I try to obtain the peer's certificate after the SSL handshake, in order to track future changes in the certificate.

```
QNetworkAccessManager nam;
nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://google.com/")));    // example URL

QObject::connect(&nam, &QNetworkAccessManager::encrypted, [](QNetworkReply *reply){
    qDebug() << reply->sslConfiguration().peerCertificate();
});
```

According to the [documentation of `QNetworkAccessManager::encrypted`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#encrypted), the above code should get access to the server's certificate:

> This signal is emitted when an SSL/TLS session has successfully completed the initial handshake. At this point, no user data has been transmitted. The signal can be used to perform additional checks on the certificate chain, for example to notify users when the certificate for a website has changed. If the reply does not match the expected criteria then it should be aborted by calling QNetworkReply::abort() by a slot connected to this signal. The SSL configuration in use can be inspected using the QNetworkReply::sslConfiguration() method.

Also, from the [documentation of `QSslConfiguration::peerCertificate()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslconfiguration.html#peerCertificate):

> Because the peer certificate is set during the handshake phase, it is safe to access the peer certificate from a slot connected to the QSslSocket::sslErrors() signal, QNetworkReply::sslErrors() signal, or the QSslSocket::encrypted() signal.

However, the certificate is always empty. The debug output of the above code (after entering the application's event loop) is:

```
QSslCertificate( "" , "" , "1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==" , () , () , QMap() , QDateTime(" Qt::LocalTime") , QDateTime(" Qt::LocalTime") )
```

On the other hand, if SSL errors where encountered, and if I connect to `sslErrors`, I *do* get the certificate. For example, for a default certificate under Ubuntu / Apache, which isn't accepted by Qt because of a missing host name in the certificate, I get for `"https://localhost"` the following:

```
QSslCertificate( "3" , "95:b0:93:f2:16:bb:22:cb" , "cXB6WctE7oZsrvZLU2BWUw==" , () , () , QMap() , QDateTime("2014-07-10 23:04:06.000 UTC Qt::UTC") , QDateTime("2024-07-07 23:04:06.000 UTC Qt::UTC") )
```

How can I get the certificate when the SSL handshake was **successful**?

I tested with the QNetworkAccessManager's signals, as well as with the QNetworkReply's signals; the results are the same.

---

**MCVE can be found at https://bitbucket.org/leemes/ssltest**, feel free to clone and fiddle:

```bash
git clone https://bitbucket.org/leemes/ssltest.git
```

---

I tested with Qt 5.4.0 and with Qt 5.3.1; results are the same.

Comment: I think, you must connect before calling GET request.

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug in Qt up to 5.4.0. It has been fixed in Qt 5.4.1.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40401